# Comparing Mantel statistics

Tags: correlation, matrix, spatial-correlation

I have the abundance of different species of birds at various locations in a country. From this data I can compute the Bray-Curtis dissimilarity matrix. This question I want to be able to answer from this is whether the dissimilarity matrix correlates better with the observed mobility of birds, as opposed to the geographical distance between locations.

What I have done so far is use the Mantel test to compute the r statistics comparing (1) the dissimilarity matrix and a geographical distance matrix, and (2) the dissimilarity matrix and the observed mobility matrix. I am getting significant correlation for both tests, but a higher (absolute value) r statistics for mobility. Is it then reasonable to compare the two r statistics and conclude that the abundances of different bird species at different locations has a stronger correlation with observed birds mobility than with geographical distances?

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable approach. Since the pertinent theoretical quantity here is $r_{g}-r_{m}$, ideally we would form a confidence interval directly on this quantity, and if it all lied below zero we could conclude that mobility correlates better. But if it's not clear to you how to do this, just building a CI on $r_g$ and $r_m$ individually and determining that there is no overlap is almost as good.

Comment: @JohnMadden Thank! Is there any chance that you can point me in the right direction for constructing the CI just on one r statistics? Is it going to require some kind of bootstrapping approach?

Comment: I don't know anything about Mantel stats but bootstrapping seems to be an approach that is used rdrr.io/cran/ecodist/man/mantel.html

Comment: @JohnMadden Thanks, I've just noticed that and I think I can just use that.